# bootstrap 4 navbar opens inside div

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using the bootstrap 4 `navbar` in an angular app. The problem is that the menu opens inside the div -- that's the best explanation I found! i.e. increases the size of the div.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="users" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Usrs
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="users">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">u1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">u2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">u3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="tickets" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Tickets
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="tickets">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">t1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">t2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">t3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is an example of what is happening in my app, and what should happen based on the bootstrap KB:

[image]

---

bootstrap version:

[image]

Comment: All the classes that you have uses are bootstrap classes only?

Comment: @TheDictator Yes. I have removed everything and this an, almost, exact copy-paste of the bootstrap reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `position:static` to `position:absolute` in `.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu` class.

```css
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {  
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="users" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Usrs
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="users">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">u1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">u2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">u3</a>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="tickets" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Tickets
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="tickets">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">t1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">t2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">t3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I was about to post about. :D